# Change color of specific item on listbox that contains a specific string on drawitem

Tags: vb.net, listbox

i want to change the color of item that contains a specific string

```
Private Sub ListBox2_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox2.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()
    If DrawItemState.Selected.ToString.Contains("specific string") Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGreen, e.Bounds)
    End If

    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
```

that is my code but not working

Comment: Explain "not working" more clearly. We need a more "spesific" description of what is wrong. Does anything different happen at all? If not, have you put a break point or logging statement in there to be sure the event even fires?

Comment: Did you set the property `DrawMode` to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` or `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`?

Answer (score 14):

Alright, first you need to set the property DrawMode of the list box to "OwnerDrawFixed" instead of Normal. Otherwise you will never get the DrawItem event to fire. When that is done it is all pretty straight forward.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()

    If ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString() = "herp" Then

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGreen, e.Bounds)
    End If
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, New System.Drawing.PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

You will have to touch this up with different colors if selected. But this should be enough for you to continue to work on. You were close, keep that in mind. :)

Comment: if my condition is dynamic then how can i do it...means i m passing the ListBox1.Items[e.index].tostring() to my db and i want to check if the return value is null the change color to black else red.

Comment: Just change the if statement to check for IsDbNull or Is Nothing on the returned value