# Visual Basic 2010 - Changing Text Color In A List Box

Tags: vb.net

How can I change the color of certain items in a dropdown combo list box? I have a program that loads the items in the list from a file, and I want certain items, determined by switches (data from other fields in the file), to be a different color. The list will be sorted.

For example - A list of 20 people is loaded, 3 of them have something that would change their name to a different color. How can this be done in code?

The ForeColor property won't work... it changes all items in the list.

Comment: What is a `dropdown combo list box`?

Comment: You want an "owner drawn" control.  For a ListBox, see [ListBox.DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx).  For a ComboBox, see [ComboBox.DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936006/change-color-of-specific-item-on-listbox-that-contains-a-specific-string-on-draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can owner draw the items and then specify the color of the item, for example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed

        Dim i As New Item()
        i.ItemColor = Color.Red
        i.Text = "Hello"

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)

        i = New Item()
        i.ItemColor = Color.Blue
        i.Text = "World"

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)

    End Sub


    Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem

        If e.Index < 0 Then Return

        Dim i As Item
        i = TryCast(ComboBox1.Items(e.Index), Item)

        If i IsNot Nothing Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Text, e.Font, New SolidBrush(i.ItemColor), e.Bounds)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Item
    Public Text As String
    Public ItemColor As Color
End Class
```

Comment: Hi... thank you for the answer, I believe it will work.  It will take me a couple days to adapt it to my program tho. I am a self-taught programmer hobbyist. But, from what I can see... does this mean I will need to apply the same procedure to the other items in the list that I don't need to be a different color?  Or can I just add those items normally?  It seems that the "DrawItem" subroutine is called by the "items.add" function... and would therefore need to have the normal items appled to the "item" class but with black (or forecolor) as the color assigned in the class.

Comment: `DrawItems` is called whenever the control draws the items.  This happens when you drop the list down by clicking the dropdown button or using the keyboard.  You could simply use the foreground color of the combo box for all items that don't need formatting.  Depending on your project layout you can figure out where to properly set this value.